# do animations in order | CSS animation

Tags: css, css-animations

Could someone tell me how to make a div that will make two animations, but the second div should be only when the first is completed?

```css
.CodeMode {
     z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    animation: MoveTop 2s, FullScreen 3s;
}
@keyframes MoveTop {
    from {top: 90%;}
    to {top: 0%;}            
}
@keyframes FullScreen {
    from {height: 10vh;}
    to {height: 100vh;}
}
```

Example of how I want that to work:
MoveTop --> Waiting until the animation ends --> FullScreen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a delay to your second animation, which is the third value after the animation name in the `animation` property.

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation):

> The animation shorthand CSS property applies an animation between
> styles. It is a shorthand for animation-name, animation-duration,
> animation-timing-function, animation-delay, animation-iteration-count,
> animation-direction, animation-fill-mode, and animation-play-state.

To apply this in your code:

```
.CodeMode {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    animation: MoveTop 2s, FullScreen 3s linear 2s;
}
```

Comment: Thx. Could you say how to save that animation? ( So it won't lose that position after 2sec? )

Comment: Got a CodePen or something I can play around with?